# Inequality for $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n^n}$.

Tags: inequality, power-series

I need to show that for $x<0$,
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n^n}<0$$
but I am completely stuck. I noted that the series is alternating, the first term is negative, but the term is only eventually decreasing. Any hint?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Notice that $n^n\geqslant n!$ and
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!} = -1+\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!}.$$

---

Edit: Unfortunately, this hint is problematic when $x<0$.  See comment by @FrankS on this post.
I preserve this post because it's a common way to start thinking.

---

Edit 2: Comparison of plots actually *show* that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n^n} < e^x-1$ when $x<0$.  The hint is not useful thus far, but apparently we can [get away with this bad math](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/260656/cant-argue-with-success-looking-for-bad-math-that-gets-away-with-it).

*Mathematica* code for the plots:

```
Plot[{x Integrate[Power[t, -x t], {t, 0, 1}], Exp[x] - 1}, {x, -3, 3}]
```

Comment: It's not true. Actually  $n^n\geq n!$

Comment: @Mesmerizedstudent Thanks.  I edited it.

Comment: You mean that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n^n}\leq \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!}=e^x-1<0$. Is it trivial for $x<0$?

Comment: @FrankS Yes, I do mean that.  You may notice that $e^x-1$ increases monotonically and that $e^0-1=0$.

Comment: $n^n\geq n!$ implies $\frac{x^n}{n^n}\leq  \frac{x^n}{n!}$ only when $n$ is even because $x<0$. Am I wrong?

Comment: @FrankS Hmm... good point!  Let me think a bit more.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\displaystyle f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n^n}$ and $\displaystyle g(x)=x\int_0^1 t^{-xt}\,\mathbb dt$.

This method starts from [the claim](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/698145/32803) that $f(x)=g(x)$ on $\mathbb R$ to provide a proof for this claim.
Thus when $x<0$, we indeed have $f(x)<0$ because $x$ is negative and $\displaystyle \int_0^1 t^{-xt}\,\mathbb dt$ is positive.

---

The $n$-th derivative of $g(x)$, written as $g^{(n)}(x)$ is (with the help of [Leibniz integral rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule))
$$
g^{(n)}(x) = n\int_0^1 (-1)^{n-1}\cdot t^{n-1 - xt}\cdot \ln^{n-1}t\,\mathbb dt
           - x\int_0^1 (-1)^{n}  \cdot t^{n   - xt}\cdot \ln^{n}  t\,\mathbb dt.
$$
Therefore, we get $\displaystyle g^{(n)}(0) = n\int_0^1 (-t\ln t)^{n-1}\,\mathbb dt$.

From integration by parts,
\begin{align}
n\int_0^1 (-t\ln t)^{n-1}\,\mathbb dt &= (n-1)\int_0^1 t\cdot (-t\ln t)^{n-2}\,\mathbb dt, \\
n\int_0^1 t\cdot (-t\ln t)^{n-2}\,\mathbb dt &= (n-2)\int_0^1 t^2\cdot (-t\ln t)^{n-3}\,\mathbb dt, \quad\cdots \\
\end{align}
we would obtain 
$$
g^{(n)}(0) = (n-1)\cdot \frac{n-2}{n}\cdot(\cdots)\cdot\frac{1}{n}\cdot\int_0^1 t^{n-1}\,\mathbb dt = \frac{(n-1)!}{n^{n-1}},
$$
which means that
$$
g(x) = g(0) + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{g^{(n)}(0)}{n!}\cdot x^n
     = 0    + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(n-1)!}{n^{n-1}\cdot n!} \cdot x^n
     = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n^n}.
$$

Therefore, $f$ is identical to $g$; when $x<0$, $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n^n}<0$. $\square$