# How to find $\int_0^\infty\frac{x!}{x^x}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, residue-calculus

I wonder how I could evaluate $$\lim_{a\rightarrow0}\int_a^\infty\frac{x!}{x^x}dx$$Where $x!$ is defined for all complex numbers with a positive real part. This is inspired by a limit I found on BlackPenRedPen. I tried using the Residue theorem using the quarter circle contour on the complex plane with a singularity at the origin, but I don't know how to use it.[image]This is the contour I am using. Consider the outer circle as a contour $\Gamma$. Let the smaller semicircle be $\gamma$. Let the radius of the big semicircle be $R$ and the radius of the smaller semicircle be $r$. Then $$\int_0^\infty f(z)dz=\lim_{(r,R)\rightarrow(0,\infty)}\left(\int_\Gamma+\int_\gamma+\int_r^Rf(z)dz+\int_{ri}^{Ri}f(z)dz\right)=2\pi i\sum_k\text{Res}(f, z_k)$$Where $f(z)=\dfrac{z!}{z^z}$, $0^0=1$, and $z_k$ are the poles of $f(z)$. After that I am stuck as I don't think $f(z)$ has any poles. Any ideas?

Comment: Is that limit supposed to be $\lim_{a\rightarrow 0}$? Also we're using the convention that $x! = \Gamma(x + 1)$ for noninteger $x$, right?

Comment: You meant $\lim_{a\to0}$, I think

Comment: You have to be really careful of $x^{-x}=\exp(-x\log x)$ as it features branch cuts. It is not holomorphic over the whole plane

Comment: @eyeballfrog Yes, thanks!

Comment: @FShrike That was what I meant, thanks!

Comment: @FShrike About your note, does this mean that the integral doesn't exist? Or do we have to take a different path? I am a bit new to Complex Analysis.

Comment: @KamalSaleh The integral exists because $x!/x^x$ is continuous on $[0,\infty)$ and decays very sharply for large $x$. But what it means is, depending on how you define $\log$, you may have to be wary. This may or may not affect residue calculations, because e.g. $x^x$ (principal value) is not holomorphic on $(-\infty,0]$

Comment: Indeed, sometimes we *like* branch cuts because they allow us to exploit the asymmetries to compute integrals (see "dogbone contours" for examples of this). I was just throwing it out there. To safely do this contour integration you're also going to need to know how to bound $\Gamma$ (which I don't...)

Comment: You don't need a small quarter-circle contour centered at $0$. There is a removable discontinuity at that point.

Comment: Interestingly enough, $\int_0^\infty \frac{(a x)^x}{x!}dx$ has a [closed form](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2478319/strange-symmetry-regarding-sum-sum-n-0-infty-fracnne-bn-gamman1) with Lambert W

Comment: The [OEIS entry](https://oeis.org/A240241) has information

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not an answer, just two funny observations:
\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty\frac{x!}{x^x}\,dx&=\int_0^\infty\frac{dx}{(1+x\log x)^2};
\\\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{n!}{n^n}&=\int_0^1\frac{dx}{(1+x\log x)^2}.
\end{align}
The second one is shown using $(1-z)^{-2}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty nz^{n-1}$ and termwise integration.

For the first one,
\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty\frac{x!}{x^x}\,dx&=\int_0^\infty\int_0^\infty y^x e^{-y}\,dy\,\frac{dx}{x^x}
\\\color{gray}{[\text{exchange}]}\quad&=\int_0^\infty e^{-y}\int_0^\infty(y/x)^x\,dx\,dy
\\\color{gray}{[x=yz]}\quad&=\int_0^\infty ye^{-y}\int_0^\infty z^{-yz}\,dz\,dy
\\\color{gray}{[\text{exchange}]}\quad&=\int_0^\infty\int_0^\infty ye^{-y(1+z\log z)}\,dy\,dz
\\\color{gray}{[\text{do the inner}]}\quad&=\int_0^\infty\frac{dz}{(1+z\log z)^2}.
\end{align}

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4143385

Comment: Woah! That was amazing!

Comment: This might be susceptible to contour integration with residues in terms of the Lambert W